# Adding few values into a single value in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, key

I have a dictionary with strings as keys, and lists of strings as values. How do I append an additional string to a given key?

For example, given:

```
dic = {"i'm": ['the']}
```

I would like to append the string 'boss' to the list of strings stored under "i'm", i.e.:

```
dic = {"i'm": ['the','boss']}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the key is in the dictionary, it's the easy solution shown several times already:

```
dic["i'm"].append("boss")
```

If the key might not be in the dictionary, either check first with `if key in dic`, use `dic.setdefault`, or make use of a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict). The defaultdict exists pretty much for the case you're considering:

```
import collections
dd = collections.defaultdict(list)
dd["i'm"].append("the")
dd["i'm"].append("boss")
print dd # defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {"i'm": ['the', 'boss']})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dic["i'm"].append("boss")
```

because `dic["i'm"]` is the list and you want to append to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by:

```
dic["i'm"].append('boss')
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's a chance (...and there almost always is unless you already checked for existence first and didn't include that code here) that the key you're looking for hasn't been added to the dict yet, just executing code like

```
dic["i'm"].append('boss')
```

will raise a `KeyError` exception. To protect yourself, you should either wrap your code in a try/except block, or use the dict's `setdefault` method to make sure there's an empty list in place first, like:

```
dic.setdefault("i'm", []).append('boss')
```

If `dic` already contains a list for the key "I'm", that's returned. If not, `setdefault` first adds an empty list to the dict and returns that. You then append to the list that either already existed or was just created for you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append to the list.  First, get the list, then append:

```
lst = dic["i'm"]
lst.append("boss")
```

Or you can do it in one step:

```
dic["i'm"].append('boss')
```